# Issue with creating a new project with Android Studio after an update

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm here to write about an issue that I've tried to fix for 3 weeks.

I think I updated a tool in the SDK within Android Studio (not sure which one).After this, I saw a lot of different issues that caused all my projects to stop working. I uninstalled it and deleted all my data of installations SDK NDK and reinstalled it, but I see the same error.

When I create a new Android Studio project I get these issues:

1. `Access Deniel`: I followed all instructions which results in the second issue.
2. `you should use version Kotlin 1.2.51 or higher`:  I
   don't use Kotlin in my project and the version of Gradle is 3.1.0, which was working correctly before.
3. Following the instructions, I updated the version of Kotlin in my project to 1.2.51, I received a lot of issues:

   ```
    Android resource compilation failed  
    Output:  C:\Users\safin\Desktop\Project\myproject 02-05- 


   2018\myproject\myproject\myproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:977: error: unescaped apostrophe in 
       string
       "Safin click,
               it is a oneself.\n\n
               All have made
               and click.\n\n
               After days.\n
               Thank you safineas.".
       C:\Users\safin\Desktop\Project\myproject 
    02-05-2018\myprojectr\myproject\myproject\app\build\intermediates
   \incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:963: 
   error: not a valid string.


   Command: C:\Users\safin\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0- 
   4818971-windows.jar\016347ebf5a2e9c410c8e5c96l7d7b16\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
       -o \
       C:\Users\safin\Desktop\Project\myproject 02-05-2018\myproject\myproject\myproject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
       C:\Users\safin\Desktop\Project\myproject 02-05-2018\myproject\myproject\myproject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
   ```

See attached screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @vamsiampolu please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get your whole problem but in that case - `error: unescaped apostrophe in string`, the string you provided SHOULD BE MODIFIED. You must add backslash before the apostrophe  like this-

```
\"Safin click, it is a oneself.\n\n All have made and click.\n\n After days.\n Thank you safineas.\"
```

Comment: The Sign   "   i don't write in my data text just when i got the bar of error message it's writing like that.